# AutoIT script does nothing from my Java code

Tags: java, path, autoit

I use TestNG framework with Selenium for Web UI tests. I have a File Download dialog box that I want to click and for that I use AutoIT.

Here is my script to handle Firefox fiel dialog box titled "Opening "

```
 Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", -2)     
 If $CmdLine[0] < 2 Then    
 ConsoleWrite("Usage: " & @ScriptName & " <Opening> <timeout in seconds>" & @CRLF)  
 Exit(1)  
 EndIf
; File save dialog is titled "Opening <file>" in Firefox and "File Download" in IE.

$title = WinGetTitle($CmdLine[1]) ; retrives whole window title $timeout = $CmdLine[2]
; wait until dialog box appears 
If WinWait($title, "", $timeout) Then ; match the window with substring
;ConsoleWrite("Found File save dialog" & @CRLF)
WinActivate($title)     
Send("!S") 
ControlClick("Opening", "", "[TEXT:&OK]")   
Exit 
Else    
  ConsoleWrite("File save dialog did not appear after " & $timeout & " seconds" & @CRLF)    
Exit(2) 
EndIf
```

This is my Java code and the path to the AutoIT exe file has been added to the system path. But the problem is that the code seems to do nothing with the exe, it executes that line and goes to the next one but the File dialog box remains as though it were unrecognized.

```
   final String type = getWebDriver().getClass().getName();
        if (type.toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {
           exe = "SelectFileDialogOptions.exe";
            commandLine = exe + " Opening " + 15;
        } else {
               //handle IE
        }
        logger.info("Executing the command '" + commandLine + "'...");
        try {
            final String[] commands = commandLine.split(" ");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new WebTestControllerException(
                    "Caught exception while trying to execute command '"
                            + commandLine
                            + "'. Exception is: "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Try changing your `ConsoleWrite()` to `MsgBox()` to try to see how far it's getting.

Comment: Tried that as well but the same result when executing the exe. When I try it manually, i.e. have the file dialog open and then run the AutoIT script from the command line, then I can see the ConsoleWrite/Msgbox show up, but still it does not click on the dialog box, probably because it couldn't get focus..

Answer (score 1):

$timeout is never defined. Your script should crash.

Comment: @Jai, but in the AutoIt script you never assign $CmdLine[2] to $timeout, that part is commented out here: `$title = WinGetTitle($CmdLine[1]) ; retrives whole window title $timeout = $CmdLine[2]`, there should be a newline before $timeout.

Comment: Oh, sorry it is just how it is formatted here, but ya in my script, it is assigned.